# Why Fetch Function making 3 request from API in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i was trying to pass the coordinate data as an argument in fetchWeatherData() which i have getting from navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() from js and which i'm able to do but i'm not aware how and why fetchWeatherData() is excute before the coordinates data updated from the useEffect hook.

[replit Link](https://replit.com/@djbravo12/WeatherApplicationOpenWeatherorg#src/context.jsx)

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react"
import axios from 'axios'

const WeatherProvider = ({ children }) => {

  //Use State Hooks
  const [cordinate, setCordinates] = useState({ lat: '', lon: '' })



  //Use Effect Hooks
  // #for cordinates
  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((currentLocationData) => {
      const { coords: { latitude: lat, longitude: lon } } = currentLocationData
      setCordinates((prev) => ({ ...prev, lat: lat.toFixed(2), lon: lon.toFixed(2) }))
    })
  }, [])


  //API Data using Axios FetchAPI
  const fetchWeatherData = async (cordinateData) => {
    let dataURL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${cordinateData.lat}&lon=${cordinateData.lon}&appid=7284c82807ce2da029ac05ea9e401a3b`

    try {
      const response = await axios.get(dataURL)
      console.log(response)
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }

  }

  // #for Fetch the Data
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchWeatherData(cordinate)
  }, [cordinate])

}
```

<img[image]>

Is am i using useEffect in correct way or something else which i can do to do not execute the fetchWeatherData() without the coodinates
Like if coordinates data value is null the return if true then only execute

Comment: useEffect will run on first render, when the lat and long are empty. If you want to avoid fetching when the coordinates are empty, you need to write a condition in your code. Another note: setCoordinates can accept simply the next state, you don't need to use previous state if you overwrite the full state...